# Session based global variable in Postgresql stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

In Oracle's PL/SQL I can create a session based global variable with the package definition.  With Postgresql's PLpg/SQL, it doesn't seem possible since there are no packages, only independent procedures and functions.

Here is the syntax for PL/SQL to declare g_spool_key as a global...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tox IS
        g_spool_key spool.key%TYPE := NULL;
        TYPE t_spool IS REF CURSOR RETURN spool%ROWTYPE;
        PROCEDURE begin_spool;
        PROCEDURE into_spool
            (
            in_txt IN spool.txt%TYPE
            );
        PROCEDURE reset_spool;
        FUNCTION end_spool
            RETURN t_spool;
        FUNCTION timestamp
            RETURN VARCHAR2;
    END tox;
```

How would I implement a session based global variable with PLpg/SQL?

Answer (score 6):

You could define some custom-variable-classes in your postgresql.conf and use it as connection-variables in your stored-procedure. See the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/runtime-config-custom.html).

Usage example for a custom-variable-class "imos":

```
imos=> set imos.testvar to 'foobar';
SET
Time: 0.379 ms
imos=> show imos.testvar;
 imos.testvar
--------------
 foobar
(1 row)

Time: 0.333 ms
imos=> set imos.testvar to 'bazbar';
SET
Time: 0.144 ms
imos=> show imos.testvar;
 imos.testvar
--------------
 bazbar
(1 row)
```

In stored-procedures you can use the built-in function [current_setting('imos.testvar')](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-admin.html).

Comment: Are these custom-variable-classes mutable?

Comment: yes, i have a class "imos" - psql output:
imos=> set imos.testvar to 'foobar';
SET
imos=> show imos.testvar;
 imos.testvar
--------------
 foobar
imos=> set imos.testvar to 'bazbar';
SET
imos=> show imos.testvar;
 imos.testvar
--------------
 bazbar

Comment: BTW, from PostgreSQL 9.2 any setting can be prefixed by any class name and support of custom_variable_classes parameter was removed.(see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-2.html#AEN111020)

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to create a temporary table, and use it to store all of your temporary variables

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_vars( 
    name varchar(64),
    value varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

You could even create a stored procedure to manage everything, creating the table if it doesn't yet exist.  One for retrieval and one for storage.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL doesn't support global (session) variables, but you should use some tricks

http://www.pgsql.cz/index.php/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks_II#Any_other_session_variables
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plperl-global.html

regards
Pavel Stehule

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there are no global variables in PL/pgSQL, although you can find ones in other PL languages that come with PostgreSQL, specifically in [PL/Perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plperl-global.html), PL/Python and PL/Tcl

Answer (score 2):

An example `PL/pgsql` script that stores and retrieves global variables from a table:

```
CREATE TABLE global_vars (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);

CREATE FUNCTION put_var(key TEXT, data TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS '
  BEGIN
    LOOP
        UPDATE global_vars SET value = data WHERE name = key;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO global_vars(name,value) VALUES (key, data);
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again
        END;
    END LOOP;
  END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION get_var(key TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS '
  DECLARE
    result TEXT;
  BEGIN
    SELECT value FROM global_vars where name = key INTO result;
    RETURN result;
  END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE FUNCTION del_var(key TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS '
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM global_vars WHERE name = key;
  END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Postgresql forums](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2006-04/msg00079.php)...

> So, a couple of questions....
>
> 1. Can you declare global values from plpgsql?
> 2. If so, is there a way of avoiding namespace pollution?
>         (perhaps the equivalent to Oracle's use of plsql package
>         variables)

plpgsql does not have global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, PostgreSQL does allow you to define custom session or transaction-local settings to your heart's content.

```sql
SET myprefix.my_bool_setting TO true;
SET myprefix.my_text_setting TO 'something';
```

Just remember to cast these settings to the correct type when you retrieve them, because they are all stored as strings:

```sql
SELECT current_setting('myprefix.my_bool_setting', true)::bool;
SELECT current_setting('myprefix.my_text_setting', true);
```