# insert_username() Function can be used for audit purpose in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have situation that I need to audit a table in Postgres.

But in Postgres there is no Function or method from which I can get the OS User.

Please suggest me how can I get the OS User in Postgres or EDB.

Also, there is an extension in `pg_available_extensions` table as `insert_username`.

Can this be used to get the OS User. If yes, how can it be used.

Comment: OS user that runs postmaster? or OS user that connects to database remotely?.. No database engine would give you that

Comment: OS user that connects to database remotely. In oracle we can get the same using sys_context.

Comment: There are some workarounds. Describe better your scenario: which os, how do you execute sql (psql?) etc...

Comment: Suppose I have a table which stores some parameters and table structure like param_table (param_id,param_value, create_user_id,update_user_id). I want to update the create_user_id and update_user_id using a trigger. and user_id would be OS user id.

Comment: I see. Postgres does not enforce client to provide this info, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934050/postgresql-and-or-sql-server-alternatives-to-oracles-sys-context

Comment: Do not add details as comment, add them to the question. How do the clients connect to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, for the general case, because PostgreSQL talks to the client over a network socket. There is no reliable way to determine the operating system user name from a TCP/IP connection from a remote host.

For unix domain sockets it's possible to require that the connecting user be the same as the PostgreSQL user using `peer` mode authentication. PostgreSQL doesn't expose the client OS username from a unix domain socket to SQL, so if you use another authentication method you can't easily find out their username even if they connected over a unix domain socket.

For loopback TCP/IP connections the host OS might run an identd, though these days almost none do. This might allow PostgreSQL to ask the other end what the username is. It supports this via the `ident` auth method, but like `peer`, you can't ask for the OS username from SQL once the user is connected.

For other users you can't reliably find out what user they are on the host OS. You would have to just trust what the client told you, and it's trivial to modify the client to lie.

You can't even get this information using a C extension function, since PostgreSQL doesn't remember it after authentication completes, and for most authentication methods it never asks the client for it in the first place. This would require protocol changes. Since the client can just lie about the host OS username, there doesn't seem to be much point.

If you want to authenticate client identity, SSL client certificates or Kerberos (SSPI, on Windows) authentication would be a better option.

Comment: hello @craig Ringer, Is this possible now as we are in Postgresql 14? Just want to know if they made any changes recently

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rely on the client providing the information in a session/transaction context variable, e.g. using [Postgres' `SET` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html):

```
SET LOCAL audit.AUDIT_USER = 'whatever-you-like';
```

[This answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104134/484293) describes how you can implement auditing based on this.

If your client is a Java application, you may also want to look at this [demo Gist](https://gist.github.com/stellingsimon/f09005f666b01f2560d73f9e603b2a97) that implements auditing of `INSERTED_BY`/`UPDATED_BY` using the above approach.